# remove escaped quotes on input string for Bun.spawn process

Tags: node.js, bun

I am trying Bun as a replacement for node and using Bun.spawn to replace exec.

when passing in a sting via `command`, `.replace(/\\"/g, '"')` is having no effect as the final `parseCommand` contains `\"Vpcs[0].Tags[?Key == 'BLAH'].Value\"`

What are some ways I can pass a final command to `Bun.spawn(command.split(' '));` so in includes `"Vpcs[0].Tags[?Key == 'BLAH'].Value"` un-escaped?

```
 ...
 command: 'aws ec2 describe-vpcs --vpc-ids MYKEY --output text --query "Vpcs[0].Tags[?Key == \'RPLVAL\'].Value"',
  key: 'BLAH',
 ....

 doStuff(command,key)

 ...
 export async function doStuff(command,key) {
 try {
 command = command.replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace("RPLVAL",key);
 // command = "aws ec2 describe-vpcs --vpc-ids MYKEY --output text --query \"Vpcs[0].Tags[?Key == \'RPLVAL\'].Value\""
 const proc = Bun.spawn(command.split(' '));
 const stdout = await new Response(proc.stdout).text();
 return stdout.trim();
  } catch (error) {
   throw error;
  }
 }
```